# How to design a load profile and which thread group needs to be used?

Tags: jmeter

I have to design a load profile based on the following conditions to validate the performance impact.

1. initially begin with 100 users and hold for 30 seconds
2. Next add the users up to 500 and hold for 30 seconds
3. Next add the users up to 1000 and hold for 60 seconds
4. Next add the users up to 1500 and hold for 60 seconds
5. Next add the users up to 2000
6. Then Shutdown the threads.

Please help me in designing the load profile and how to calculate the duration of the test based on the above conditions?
Also, observed in few cases when I used Constant Timer for the transactions, some of the requests are not executed. Which timer is better to hold for the page to get loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest is going for [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which provides possibility to implement whatever workload patterns you want and displays the anticipated load in the chart

Example settings:

[image]

Ultimate Thread Group can be installed as a part of [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri and would like to know why a few of the requests are skipped out during the load test. what I have observed I have used 3 transactions and each transaction has a couple of requests e.g. Login transaction, Search transaction, and logout transaction.  After the execution (execution time is 20 mins). When I imported the .jtl file in the summary report. only Login transactions show 2000 or more Samples and the remaining transactions show fewer samples?  But when I  execute with 100 users, I am getting correct output

Comment: It happens because when the 3 minutes and 30 seconds pass JMeter sends termination signal to all threads and they may stop in the middle of the transaction.

Comment: How to calculate the total execution time to get the response for all the requests with 2000 threads using the above Load profile?  E.g. There are a total of 100 requests &  only 50% of the request sent to the server within 3 mins 30 seconds remaining were missed out.